# Can we compare fractions with same numerator and different denominator

Tags: fractions

If we are given the 2 fractions

4/7 and 5/7

5/7 is greater

What if we had

1/8 and 1/9

Can I say that the fraction with a greater denominator is less

Comment: Consider $$\frac{a}{b}-\frac{a}{c}=\frac{ac-ab}{bc}=\frac{a}{bc}(c-b)$$ If $a,b,c>0$ , this is positive for $c>b$ , negative for $c<b$ and $0$ for $b=c$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. The argument goes as follows: Start with the fact that $9>8$. Dividing by $8$ on both sides gives us $9/8>1$. Dividing by $9$ on both sides gives us $1/8>1/9$.